# On change of textbox value select a value in dropdown list using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, arraylist, combobox, textbox

I am using given below code in HTML page to change the value of dropdown list which must less than or equal to the entered value in text box.

**Javascript-**

```
function abc(){
                var dp = document.getElementById("oildate1");
                document.getElementById("ocb3").text = dp;
                }
```

**HTML and PHP Code**

```
<input type="text" name="oildate1" id="oildate1" onChange="abc()">
                    <select name="ocb3" id="ocb3">
                            <?php 
                                include 'connection.php';
                                $sql = mysqli_query($con,"select Sno,dateoil, replace(dateoil,'-','') as trimmed_date from dieselrates WHERE Transname='$Transname' order by dateoil ASC");
                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
                                echo "<option value=$row[Sno]>$row[trimmed_date]</option>";
                                }
                            ?>
                    </select>
```